# Kotlin if condition idiom

Tags: kotlin

So I'm new to kotlin and was looking for a way to express an if condition with it's action in a more idiomatic way. So I have an object that behaves like a collection so I can call any/filter on it. Basically I want to check if that collection has a specific key, and if it has, I want to check then if the value is the one I'm expecting. If both conditions are true, I want to apply some action.

I guess I could just write:

```
exists = collection.any() { item ->
   item.key() == "mykey" && item.value() == "myvalue"
}

if(exists) {
  // do something
}
```

Is there a better way to write the above code in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't overthink it. I think something like this is more readable:

```kotlin
if (collection["myKey"] == "myValue") {
 // do something
}
```

Note that `collection["myKey"]` has an optional return type, so if your key isn't in the collection it would return `null`. This is going off the idea that your collection is very similar to a map or set as both would return `null` for an undefined element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the element right when you find it, you could say:

```
collection.first { it.key == "myKey" && it.value == "myValue" }
        .let {
            // Do something with it here
            println("Found: $it")
        }
```

Note the use of `it` saves some typing and is good as long as one can tell what it is from looking at the expresion.

Also `first()` returns the element or an exception if not found, so consider  `firstOrNull()` if it is possible no elemente will satisfy the condition.

If you're only interested in the mere existence or not of the element then is probably better:

```
if (collection.any { it.key == "myKey" && it.value == "myValue" }) {
    // Do something
}
```

If your predicate gets complicated, move it into a function:

```
fun code() {
    if (collection.any(::predicate)) {
        // Do something
    }
}

private fun predicate(it: Item) =
        it.key == "myKey" && it.value == "myValue"
```

Comment: In examples with any(), the code block will execute just for the items that have returned true in the condition, and not for all items in the collection, right ?

Comment: `any()` will return true if at least one element in the collection matches the predicate, not all the elements will be processed.

Comment: My mistake then. Could you provide an example with iterating only over those items that satisfy the condition ?

Comment: In that case you will want to use `filter` which will filter out the ones that don't satisfy the predicate, for example: collection.filter `{ it.isValid() } .forEach { println("valid: $it")}`. I also recommend you to check the collections guide: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html